# DQL and SQL query return more data than QueryBuilder ..., how? why?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, symfony-2.3

I have the following piece of code in a Doctrine Repository:

```
$em           = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb           = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query_result = $qb->select('IDENTITY(l.customer) as customer, COUNT(l) AS total_unattached')
                   ->from('QuoteBundle:License', 'l')
                   ->leftJoin('QuoteBundle:Agreement', 'a', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->andX(
                       'l.agreementType = a.agreementType',
                       'l.customer = a.customer'
                   ))
                   ->where('l.customer IN (:implode)')
                   ->setParameter('implode', implode(',', $customers_id))
                   ->andWhere('a.agreementNumber IS NULL')
                   ->groupBy('l.customer')
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getArrayResult();
```

From the code above if I do `count($query_result)` I will get `1`. 
‌‌

> count($query_result)
>       ‌< 1

Now the funny thing is as follow:

I have tried the DQL generated by the previous Query Builder `$qb->getDQL()`:

```
SELECT
  IDENTITY(l.customer) AS customer,
  COUNT(l)             AS total_unattached
FROM
  QuoteBundle:License l
LEFT JOIN QuoteBundle:Agreement a WITH l.agreementType = a.agreementType AND l.customer = a.customer
WHERE l.customer IN (21, 23) AND a.agreementNumber IS NULL GROUP BY l.customer
```

And surprise I got 2 values:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'customer' => string '21' (length=2)
      'total_unattached' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'customer' => string '23' (length=2)
      'total_unattached' => string '17' (length=2)
```

I have tried the SQL generated by the previous Query Builder `$qb->getQuery()->getSQL()`:

```
SELECT
  l0_.CustomerSiteID AS sclr_0,
  COUNT(l0_.id)      AS sclr_1
FROM license l0_
  LEFT JOIN agreement a1_
    ON (l0_.AgreementTypeID = a1_.AgreementTypeID AND l0_.CustomerSiteID = a1_.CustomerSiteID)
WHERE l0_.CustomerSiteID IN (21, 23) AND a1_.AgreementNumber IS NULL
GROUP BY l0_.CustomerSiteID
```

And surprise I got *again* 2 values:

```
21  1
23  17
```

Below is the result of the following statements:

```
dump($qb->getParameters());
dump($qb->getDQL());
dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL());
dump($query_result);
```

[image]

Having that, why the `$query_result` is having only one?

**Update:**

I've tried also `getResult()` instead of `getArrayResult()` and the result is the same, see images below:

[image]

Notice how the query generated by the previous QB returns two rows instead of one:

[image]

Comment: does using **getResult()** instead of **getArrayResult()** return the correct amount of values?

Comment: @lordrhodos no, it does not return the correct amount, see my edit (with images :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the parameters sent as `:implode` - you are sending a string `"21,23"` which is then parsed as a the number `21` only, dropping the second id. MySQL is known to do that (with a warning which you do not see here).

It can be seen from the SQL statement being prepared - the `l0.CustomerSiteID IN (?)` condition only contains one `?` but it should look like `(?, ?)` for it to work properly.

Use the array directly, without *imploding*. QB should handle that and generate the right SQL.